# Dynamically capture a div position

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to display/capture a divs top value while it changes as it is being animated similar to the Chrome dev tools Elements tab?  I have tried getComputedStyle and getPropertyValue but doesn't work.  This is what I have tried so far

```
var top_sq = document.getElementById("square"),
style_sq_top = getComputedStyle(top_sq),
sq_top = style_sq_top.getPropertyValue("top"),
act_sq_top = sq_top.substring(0, 3);

var tv = document.getElementById("top_value").text = sq_top;

$("#btn1").click(function(){
$("#square").animate({top:"300px"}, 3000);
 tv.toString;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QYVQT/

Comment: Try to use - step or progress - of 'animate' http://api.jquery.com/animate/ or use animationIteration event http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Comment: Thank you guys.  These both answer my question, think I have to give the check to Amadeus cause he was the first to pipe in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code you've provided is that `tv` does not change dynamically as the box is animated. Remember, `sq_top` is simply a number. When you set `tv` equal to `sq_top`, you're setting it equal to a number. Thus the value of `tv` doesn't change as the box moves.

Instead, recalculate it each time. You can use the `progress` property of the `.animate()` function to do this. See here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1856-using-jquery-s-animate-step-callback-function-to-create-custom-animations.htm.

Code using the `$.progress()` function:

```
var square = document.getElementById("square"),
    squareTop = null,
    squareTopString = null,
    tvDiv = document.getElementById('top_value');

$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#square").animate(
        {top:"300px"},  
        {
            duration: 3000,
            progress: function(){
                /* get the top of the square */
                squareTop = square.style.top;
                /* format it correctly */
                dotLoc = squareTop.indexOf('.');
                if(dotLoc == -1){
                    squareTopString = squareTop;
                } else{
                    squareTopString = squareTop.substring(0, dotLoc) + 'px';
                }
                /* display the current top position, e.g. "200px" */
                tvDiv.innerHTML = squareTopString; 
            },
            easing: "swing"
        }
    );
});
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KLhzp/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using [jQuery `animate()`'s `step()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step) callback.

```
var top_sq = document.getElementById("square"),
    style_sq_top = getComputedStyle(top_sq),
    sq_top = style_sq_top.getPropertyValue("top"),
    act_sq_top = sq_top.substring(0, 3);

var $tv = $("#top_value")
$tv.text(act_sq_top);

$("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#square").animate({
        top: "300px"
    }, {
        duration: 3000,
        step: function (now, fx) {
            pos = Math.round(now);
            $tv.text(pos);
        }
    });
});
```

And here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QYVQT/2/