# Get a direct reference to a JavaScript property

Tags: javascript, reference, pass-by-reference

After answering [this question about using the style.top property of a div in jQuery's `$.animate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554307/dynamically-capture-a-div-position/23554365#23554365), I started to wonder if there was a way to do it more in line with what the OP had thought (s)he could do.

The question is: can we get a direct reference to an object's property when that property is a primitive type?

For example, if you had an object called `myDiv`, you could get a reference to its `style` property, because that's an object, but is there any way to get a reference to the `top` property of `style` so that when this changes, you don't have to retrieve it again and again? (Note: I'm not saying this retrieval is computationally significant. This is just a question about what's possible, not what's good practice.)

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.style.top = "100px";
var myDivStyle = myDiv.style;
var myDivStyleTop = myDiv.style.top;

myDiv.style.top = "200px";
console.log(myDivStyle.top); // will print "200px"
console.log(myDivStyleTop); // will obviously print "100px"
```

Is there a way to reference that `top` property directly without going through `style`? My instinct is no, but JS has surprised me before, so I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: I want to say no as well...objects assignments are merely references - but that `top` property will assign the value and keep it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** A variable are just simple container that can hold a value. Assigning a new value to a variable can **never** change the value of another variable or property.

In this regard, it doesn't matter whether the variable holds a primitive values or an object, that's just how variables work.

Comment: I disagree with the primitives part of your answer. If your variable references an object, another variable can change the same object that both variables refer to. `var a=b={a:1}; a.a=2;console.log(b.a)`

Comment: I never denied that. But that's not assigning a new value to the variable then. That is reading the variable value and *mutating* it  (the object). I'm talking about `var a = b = {a:1}; a = 2;console.log(b);`, which is what the OP tries to do here.

Comment: I know, defining pointers and references is hard. But I think do know what you mean, like in C++, you have actual references to variables, not just to memory addresses of the actual data. The only way in JS to have two references to the same thing is through an object (not a primitive), as I've noted in my answer.

Comment: Exactly. Or [references in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). Maybe I was a bit vague in my answer. I'm not saying there is not difference between primitive values or objects. I meant that it doesn't matter what value to the variable has, assigning a new value to it doesn't change another variable.

Comment: "assigning a new value to [a variable] doesn't [in of itself] change another variable." Well said. I think that answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. Primitives are immutable and never stored by reference.

From MDN

> ## object reference
>
> A link to an object. Object references can be used as if they were the objects they link to. The concept of object references arises when assigning the same object to more than one property. Each assigned property does not hold a copy of the object. Instead, they hold object references that link to the same object. In practice, this means that if the object is modified, all properties referring to the object reflect the modification.
>
> ## primitive, primitive value
>
> A data that is not an object and does not have any methods. *JavaScript has 5 primitive datatypes: **string**, number, boolean, null, undefined*. With the exception of null and undefined, all primitives values have object equivalents which wrap around the primitive values, e.g. a String object wraps around a string primitive. **All primitives are immutable**.

Comment: Thanks for the reference (pun?).